# Detecting new dependencies introduced on build machine

Tags: c++, .net, build, windows-update, winsxs

We *try* to not require that our users have all the latest Microsoft patches.  Some of our customers use highly controlled environments for these Windows machines - often involving laborious approval procedures before applying updates and, sometimes, the machines are kept off their LANs.  We try to specify a minimum Windows Service Pack and then provide anything else needed on our installer packages.

Our current practice is to only update build machines when we have the motivation to do a manual update - and hope that we do not overlook a newly introduced version of our applications' dependencies.  Unfortunately, sometimes a Windows/Microsoft update is run on our build machines during a late development phase and a new dependency is introduced without immediate detection.

Do you have suggestions on practices and policies to better handle this, possibly including automatic detection of newly introduced version dependencies, particularly for Visual Studio native C++ and .NET projects?

Comment: I have not personally seen issues with updates to the operating system introducing versioning dependencies to my own .NET code.  What kind of dependencies do you see?

Comment: I assume it's the same via .NET manifests but maybe it's not: after applying an update that changes a C++ runtime library on the build machine, the next build of an application that depends on the library may cause the new version to be required.  
One symptom is a side-by-side error when attempting to run the newly built application on a machine that does not have the particular Windows update applied.